# Where do you find Mac App Store analytics

Tags: app-store-connect, analytics, mac-app-store

I have recently published my first Mac app onto the Mac App Store, forgive me if this is a stupid question but i can find no place on iTunes Connect that shows the analytics for it, the App Analytics section on iTunes Connect only shows my iOS app? There must be somewhere to see how many units i have sold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i contacted apple an there reply was:

App Analytics is available only for iOS developers at this time, and it reports data only from customers using iOS 8 and above. Therefore you will not see data from your Mac app.

If you would like, I can submit feedback on your behalf for a possible future enhancement. If this is something you would like me to do, please reply with a clarification of your request, and I will be happy to send it up for you.

So the short answer is there is nowhere for you to find how many downloads/revenue you have earned. Which is well, shit